# Codeigniter link button to another view not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<button onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url();?>Guesser/guess'">Start!</button>
```

Just displays an empty web page with about:blank as the url

Comment: Try with index.php <?php echo base_url();?>index.php/guesser/guess if not you may need to set custom routes in application > config > routes.php

Comment: @wolfgang1983 doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url();?>Guesser/guess'" value="Start!">
```